# how to import seaborn egg (new 0.6.dev) into python

Tags: python, python-2.7, seaborn

I got the developmental version using this in cmd prompt (after uninstalling the old package):

```
pip install git+git://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn.git#egg=seaborn
```

Now when I try to import in canopy it still says I am using the old version.

```
import seaborn as sns
help(sns)
```

And at the end of the output I get:

```
VERSION
0.5.1
```

How do I need to set this up?

Comment: Are you sure you are using the interpreter that it was installed for?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham    If by interpreter you mean Canopy, the egg is installed here: C:\Users\[Name]\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\Lib\site-packages\seaborn-0.6.dev0-py2.7.egg-info. I don't see why it shouldn't work.

Comment: Do you have any other versions of python installed?

Comment: Yes. I have both 2.7 and 3.4 downloaded for ipython notebook but I only have canopy with python 2.7. Do you think that's causing the problem?

Comment: probably -- you need to be sure that `pip` is pointing to the same python as your interpreter